# Allow autocompletion for the tags in Ansible playbooks

Tags: bash, ansible

I would like to use auto completion for the tags found in the playbook I specify on the command line. Thus when I use `--tags` option, I want to use `TAB` to complete a tag name that should follow the option.

Does it possible? Where should I start?

Comment: There is a [support for auto-completion since ansible 2.9](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#shell-completion) but this does not include listing particular values for a given options. So it will not fulfill your requirement (yet...?).

Comment: Let's say you export a variable to the bash environment. Right after, with the next command you will be able to autocomplete it's name using 'TAB'. I am searching to understand how, in this case, value found in the file, the tag name, can be immediately added to completion.

Comment: Which shell are you using ? For bash, you can [see this introduction](https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1)

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: I did not looked at the completion code yet, but looks like ansible-playbook completion is written poorly. I wanted it to complete my file names when I use -l (--limit) and @ symbol, but it did not work for me. It even did not completed options! (I am not completely sure, maybe I did something wrong).
The solution is only one - to develop a proper completion script. Then upstream it.

Comment: https://github.com/dysosmus/ansible-completion - this repo is a good start. It is also in a https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ansible-completion-git/